# Advanced Calc: Saddle Point

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x, y) = −x^3 + y^2$ . Show that $(0, 0)$ is a saddle point.

I know that I cannot use the second derivative test for this function, and I should find the curve of intersection of the graph of f with the $xz$-plane. I'm thinking that $z=0$, so the curve of intersection is $y^2 = -x^3$. Where should I proceed from here?

Comment: The $xz$-plane is the set of points for which $y=0$ (not $z=0$ as you wrote). If you think about how this function's value changes as we vary $x$ near 0 while keeping $y=0$ fixed, you might see why $(0,0)$ is not a local maximum or minimum.

Comment: There are various definitions of "saddle point." My favourite is "There exists a line through the point along which f has a local min at the point AND there exists a line through the point along which f has a local max at the point." By this definition, (0,0) is NOt a saddle point of f, since there exists no line through (0,0) along which f has a local max at (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** If $(0,0)$ is a maximum, then shifting the value of $x,y$ away from $0$ should decrease $f(x,y)$. If $(0,0)$ is a minimum, then shifting the value of $x,y$ away from $0$ should increase the value $f(x,y)$. Otherwise, $(0,0)$ is a saddle.

Now at $(0,0)$, what happens to the value of $f(x,y)$ if you change the $y$ value away from $0$, even a tiny bit? [Holding $x$ constant at $0$.]

Also at $(0,0)$ what happens if you shift the $x$-value from $0$ to anything tiny and positive, what happens to the value of $f(x,y)$? Now what if you shift the $x$-value from $0$ to anything tiny and negative, what happens to the value of $f(x,y)$? [Each case, holding $y$ constant at $0$.]

Combining all this information above, can you see why $(0,0)$ must be a saddle point for $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $y=x^2$. Then you have $f(x,y(x))=-x^3+x^4=g(x)$. since this function has an inflection point at $x=0$ you have that $(0,0)$ can't be a local maximum or a local minimum and therefore it is a saddle point.